# How to add a contact to contactgroup using Kentico Rest API?

Tags: kentico, kentico-api

There is a POS windows application where a store manager processes bills for customers. Our client want us to provide them an API service where this service will add a customer as a contact and also be assigned to a POS contacts contact group in Kentico 12.

Is there any possibility to achieve this using Kentico 12 Rest API out of the box feature?

Answer (score 4):

In Kentico contact membership in a contact group is stored in **om.contactgroupmembercontact** object type. So I believe the following should work:

POST request to URL: ~/rest/om.contactgroupmembercontact?format=json

And the following data:

```
{
    "ContactGroupMemberContactGroupID":yourContactGroupID,
    "ContactGroupMemberType":0,
    "ContactGroupMemberRelatedID":yourContactID,
    "ContactGroupMemberFromManual":true // Manually added contact
}
```

You need to know ContactGroupID and ContactID which can be retrieved with other queries.